# Crystal Library

Tags: oscillator, crystal

I am using the ABM8G-12.000MHZ crystal. Should I plot the footprint of this crystal either bottom view or top view?

[image]

Comment: Presumably (but not 100% certainly) the two ground pins will be electrically joined. If so you can test with a meter and determine which view applies. | The bottom view is looking at the crystal (not the board) .

Comment: Question is clear enough. With multiple answers close voting seems inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I plot the footprint of this crystal either bottom view or top view?

If you meant designing of footprint, then you should use recommended land pattern dimensions for designing the footprint.

[image]

Comment: Which view should I number the crystal?

Comment: In the datasheet it is mentioned, that "Per the Top Marking from left to right, Pin 1 is always located on the bottom left."

Answer (score 0):

When they say Top View, what they usually mean is when the component is placed on a PCB and you are looking down on it. As such the dotted lines for the pads are showing what the pads are connected to electrically (sort of like a physical schematic). The Bottom View is what you see when you flip the part over and look at the pads on the part. This is useful as a point of reference because pin 1 of the part has a physically different looking pad than the other three (i.e. on of the corners of that pad is notched). So if you label pin 1 of the footprint on the PCB you can orient the part correctly with a visual check.

In terms of numbering, the two views are entirely self-consistent. The top view is flipped vertically with respect to the bottom view, as if you rotated the physical part in your hand. Pins 1 and 3 connect to the crystal terminals, and pins 2 and 4 should connect to GND of your system.

Answer (score 0):

The same way your PCB layout software works, which is usually as seen from the top.

Answer (score 0):

1. For PCB Assy Dwg, use the top, which is the correct CCW orientation pin view with Pin 1 in Bottom Left

---

This would look like the part except there is no fiducial or 1 on part. Just the Text.

[image]

---

This is too much info

[image]

This has logical and Physical with p/n marking.

But what if you have a 2nd source?

---

[image]

This is the correct view for Assy Dwg.

Then on Silk Screen add a fiducial marking, \$\cdot\$, if hand making prototypes.

---

For your part Library or Master Register for all sources, you must plot all 3 views, top, bottom and land pattern.

Crop & Sharpen

[image]